# Couldn't install pylint in Python2.7 and get not matched errors even install with the local setup.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pylint, python-config

For the developing environment constrained I have to use `Python2.7` in the **Windows10**.
So I choose to install `pylint` as the linter I use in the Administrator Mode.

```
pip install "pylint<2.0.0"
```

But it only outputs as follows:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
>   after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 
>   'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pylint/

And this message repeat many times then give such output:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pylint<2.0.0 (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for pylint<2.0.0

So I download a 1.9.3 version in the [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/1.9.3/). 
And tried to install it with `setup.py` in the Administrator Mode as follows:

```
python setup.py install
```

BUT also get the same problems as before:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pylint/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pylint/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pylint/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pylint/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pylint/
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pylint==1.9.3 (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pylint==1.9.3

And I also tried the older version like **1.8.4**, **1.7.4** and so on.

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytest-runner/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytest-runner/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytest-runner/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytest-runner/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pytest-runner/
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest-runner (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytest-runner
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
>
> subprocess.check_call(cmd)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
>
> ```
> raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
> ```
>
> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\Users\EU\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyjj78l40', '--quiet', 'pytest-runner']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "setup.py", line 178, in
>
> ```
> install()
> ```
>
> File "setup.py", line 175, in install
>
> **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools__init__.py", line 143, in setup
>
> _install_setup_requires(attrs)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools__init__.py", line 138, in _install_setup_requires
>
> dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 721, in fetch_build_eggs
>
> replace_conflicting=True,
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 783, in resolve
>
> replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 1066, in best_match
>
> return self.obtain(req, installer)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 1078, in obtain
>
> return installer(requirement)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 777, in fetch_build_egg
>
> return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
>
> raise DistutilsError(str(e))
>
> distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\Users\EU\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyjj78l40', '--quiet', 'pytest-runner']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

BUT it still got other problems here, which is messed with me all day.

So could anyone help me or give some hints?
Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should avoid Python2.7 if possible, since it is [no longer supported](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

You might be behind a firewall that blocks these connections. If that's your problem, try [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4417#issuecomment-303957548).